# How to solve "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Tags: java, scala

When I run the Scala program "Stanford Topic model Toolbox", it show the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to unwrap the InvocationTargetException to see the real cause of the problem.

Comment: InvocationTargetException means "something bad has happend when trying to invoke that method" and you will find the original exception in cause. Fix that and you'll fix the InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the cause property of the `InvocationTargetException`. It will show the exception thrown in the first place. Or just list the whole stack trace. You should find the first exception towards the end.